# Crop an image on resize from one specific side

Tags: html, css

Is it possible to control the direction from which a picture is cropped using CSS?
I have a product shot that has it's subject on the left side of the image.
I need to be able to not crop the left size on browser resize.

Right now the I'm setting the picture as background image in order to have control over the scaling and cropping but directional cropping does not seem to be a thing.

Below is a link to codepen:
http://codepen.io/samratrocks/pen/LxGjjR
and below is the CSS code I'm using on the DIV.

```
.img-holder {
    height: 300px;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: center center;
    background-size: auto auto;
}
```

As you can see from the pen, when you decrease the size of the browser, the image gets cropped while maintaining the center. I want to crop the image, while maintaining the left side of the image.

Has anyone has this problem / solved this problem before?

Comment: share also HTML and CSS used so far , to show what you'r up to and where you are stuck. so it makes a proper question and one could answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out it's a rather stupid question.
I just changed the position to left and kept the size as auto and now the image only crops from right.

```
.img-holder {
    background-position: left center;
    background-size: auto auto;
```

Answer (score 0):

You might be able to do something in javascript, but it sounds like a hacky solution to me. Instead, I'd recommend having two versions of the image, one cropped and one not, and using media queries or a css framework like bootstrap. This way, when the browser is resized to a certain dimension, your page will use the correct image automagically.

Comment: That wouldn't work because since I can't scale the image, the sides would get cropped on browser resize.

Comment: Note that this will reduce the seo of that image, it's best to have one version of an image that gets lots of views, that 2 that each get half the views